Why can't I run a small Java program directly in Android Studio without converting it to Kotlin first?
I am starting Android Development. When I try to run a Java code it doesn't run, but when I convert the same code to Kotlin the run button appears, and the output is visible.
// Kotlin 
package com.example.helloworld   

object ne {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Hello")
    }
}

//Java
public class ne{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

Why doesn't the Java code run, and also what is the @JvmStatic that appears  after converting the code?

Please post your code as (formatted) text, not as a screenshot.

Sorry i will remember from the next time

No, please also update this question so it helps others that have the same problem as you.

you have probably made your project in Kotlin make a new one in java

pick it here

accept my Ans if helps

You don't have to advertise your own answer. The OP will accept an answer if it solves the issue / answers the question. Not more, not less.

@arkascha sorry will not do it again but people don't accepts even when it helped them as they don't know they can even accept i dint like a week ago

This will not affect whether Java code can run.

Yes, indeed it often happens that new users asking questions won't accept answers. Don't get frustrated over that. They will start doing that once they receive a hint on that issue, which they will. And then they will accept answers to older questions too. That will all sort itself out in the long run. The issue with advertising comments like yours above: imagine all answers and questions getting flooded with begging comments like that ...

I made a new project and selected java as the language , wrote the same code, the run button was still not there . Is there a way to run the java code alone  ?

Even if Changing the project language runs the Java code, why can't I run it in the Kotlin Project if i can create a java file and use its components in my kotlin file.
